# How do I use a subscription in flow-router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, subscription, flow-router

```
// server/publications.js
Meteor.publish('crewMessages', function(crewId) { 
  return CrewMessages.find({crewId: crewId}, {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: 100});
});

// lib/router.js
FlowRouter.route('/crew/:crewSlug', {
    subscriptions: function(params) {
        console.log("Subscribed to this crew's chat messages:", params.crewSlug);
        this.register('crewMessages', Meteor.subscribe('crewMessages', params.crewSlug));
    },
    action: function(params) {
      FlowLayout.render("layout", { content: 'crew' });
    }
});
```

And inside my `crew.html` template:

```
<div class="container">
  {{> crewChat}}
</div>
```

And my `crewChat.html/js`:

```
Template.crewChat.helpers({
  messages: function() {
    return CrewMessages.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}}); 
  }
});

<div class="ui feed">
  {{#each messages}}
    {{> crewChatMessage}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

In my `crewChat.js` file, how can I use the subscription I set in Flow-router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create a functional example for you at MeteorPad

http://meteorpad.com/pad/Ba5DTe94NjFi3ZTPA/Playground_Flow-Router_Chat

Most important to your question is, that you just can use the Collection inside your template with `Collection.find()` because you are only subscribed to the crews messages via route subscription.

Each message can be accessed as normal document `see template showChatMessage`

Hope that makes it clear for you

Cheers
Tom

PS: You can also change the url inside the meteorpad to also switch to chats for team2 and team3

Comment: Great answer Tom, thank you for taking the time to streamline this example. I now understand a bit more on how subscriptions work in Meteor.